# Assigning a macro value in Make from a shell command

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

The I/O blocksize is going to figure prominently in a Makefile I need to write, so I need a way to calculate it.  This script does what I want:

```
> cat blksz.bash
#!/bin/bash
bsl=$(du --block-size=1 testfile)
bsl=($bsl)
echo ${bsl[0]}
```

(Someone might have a better way to do it, but if you can bear with me, that's not really the most general point of the question.)

I can call this from my Makefile, and it works fine:

```
> cat Makefile
BLOCKSIZE := $(shell ./blksz.bash)
blocksize:
        echo $(BLOCKSIZE)
> make blocksize
echo 4096
4096
```

Then I think this is such a small script, wouldn't it be better to just put it in the Makefile.  But then it no longer works.

```
> cat Makefile
BLOCKSIZE := $(shell bsl=$(du --block-size=1 testfile) ; \
               bsl=($bsl) ; \
               echo ${bsl[0]})
blocksize:
        echo $(BLOCKSIZE)
> make blocksize
echo
```

i.e. `BLOCKSIZE` is never defined.  Clearly, I have defined the shell command incorrectly in the Makefile.  Can anyone tell me the correct way to do this?  Also, there might be better ways to get the block size, but the broader issue of how to get a return value out of a shell command so the Makefile can see it will probably come up again for me at some point, and that is fundamentally what I am trying to figure out.

One last thing, regarding duplicate questions, there are a few similar questions around, but nothing that gets quite at what I am asking, AFAICT.  I think what makes this different is that I am using variables *within* the shell command, and somehow their contents are being lost.

Comment: To answer your question directly, `$` is a special character to make (it introduces make variables and functions) so if you want to pass it to the shell you have to escape it as `$$`.  Plus the issue of shell variables not being available in `/bin/sh`.  So your command must be: `BLOCKSIZE := $(shell /bin/bash -c 'bsl=$$(du --block-size=1 testfile) ; bsl=($$bsl) ; echo $${bsl[0]}')`.  However as described below, there are better ways to do this.

Comment: @MadScientist  The double $ addresses the more general question that I had.  Will help me in the future with other shell commands that use variables.  If you turn this into an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I edited my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question directly, `$` is a special character to make (it introduces make variables and functions) so if you want to pass it to the shell you have to escape it as `$$`. Plus the issue of array variables not being available in `/bin/sh` as mentioned by @tripleee.

So your command must be:

```
BLOCKSIZE := $(shell /bin/bash -c 'bsl=$$(du --block-size=1 testfile) ; bsl=($$bsl) ; echo $${bsl[0]}').
```

Personally I don't like to use bash-specific features nor awk but YMMV.  A better way to do this IMO is to use the `stat` program:

```
BLOCKSIZE := $(shell stat -c %s testfile)
```

If you don't want to `stat`, then another way would be:

```
BLOCKSIZE := ${shell set -- $$(du --block-size=1 testfile); echo $$1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you hack `SHELL=/bin/bash` your shell commands will be executed by `/bin/sh`. But you don't need Bash for this.

```
BLOCKSIZE := $(shell du --block-size=1 testfile | awk '{ print $$1 }')
```